# Position Footer Div at bottom of Last Page (on screen and print)

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a requirement to position a div on the bottom of the last page when printing. Consider I have a page set up as follows.

```
[div id=Header]
[/div]

[div id=Lines]
     x Number of lines that could potentially span 1 or more pages
[/div]

[div id=Footer  style="position: absolute; bottom: 20px; left: 4px; right: 4px;"]
[/div]
```

No this code is fine if there are a few lines on the page, but if there are more than just a few the footer then overlaps some of the lines. Is it possible in CSS to fix the footer to the bottom of the page, but to attach to the bottom of the second page if the lines fill the first page.

I think its the position absolute that is causing the problem. Has anyone else done this that has an alternative? I couldnt find another answer with a solution that worked for me

ps. sorry about the square brackets, couldnt work out how to get the markup in otherwise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to obtain this result: http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/QAs78/

To let the footer stay at the bottom, you need to wrap your elements, and set the current wrapper style:

```
#wrapper{
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
```

Remember also to set

```
html,body{
    padding:0; /* to avoid y scrollbar */
    height:100%
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats a really useful site. That is almost what i need. I also have a comment div, and a with thanks div that should fit halfway between the lines and the footer. I have updated the example on the site you provided. My problem now is that the footer still overwrites the with thanks div and comment div but stops when it hits the lines div.    http://jsfiddle.net/QAs78/17/

Comment: This approach suffers from [bug 267029](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=267029) on Firefox. (The footer appears at the bottom of the first page and overlaps content.)